# Error: 'String' is not convertible to 'String!'

Tags: swift, string, reactive-cocoa

```
mapView.rac_valuesForKeyPath("userTrackingMode", observer: self).subscribeNextAs { 
// block handling
```

I get an error `'String' is not convertible to 'String!'`. Any suggestions what this may mean?

I used to think, that `String!` is same as `String`, so it is unwrapped `String?`...

- Xcode 7.3.1
- Swift 2.2
- ReactiveCocoa 4.1.0

Comment: I think the compiler is reporting a wrong error. Maybe try `let key: String! = "userTrackingMode"` and then use `key` instead of the literal. That could help the compiler to print the real error.

Comment: @Sulthan You were right. Post this please as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the compiler is reporting a wrong error.

You can simplify the expression using

```
let key: String! = "userTrackingMode"
```

and then use `key` instead of the literal.

That will simplify the expression and will help the compiler to print the real error.

Type inferring is complicated and when the compiler doesn't find a valid type combination, it can show you a wrong error.